# Creating single contour defining boundary between sea and land using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, dem, contour

I am trying to create a map with ArcMap.

The area I am working on is a seasite and I found that in some parts the cells appear as white.

Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

Moreover, I would like to create a single contour along the seacoast just to highlight the boundary between the land and the sea.

Does anybody know how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your second question, you will have to digitize the contour line yourself using a basemap. To do this, create a line shapefile, specify the proper coordinate system and bring the new shapefile into your map document from Catalog. I find it easiest to digitize if you symbolize the line in pink with a width of 2.0.  Right click on the new shapefile, click edit features and click start editing. Use the [curve tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/through_start_middle_and_end_points_Arc/01m700000033000000/) to outline the boundary between the land and sea on the basemap. Press F2 to complete the shape (quick useful shortcut when digitizing!). Save your edits and stop editing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking a different approach and downloading preexisting coastal boundaries rather than digitizing them yourself.  Many good datasets exist, however, [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) is among the best.  I would particularly recommend the high detail (1:10m) [Coastlines](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-coastline/) dataset.